# Paginating WordPress main loop

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, pagination

I am using a WP theme that uses in the archive.php main loop. The code is like that:

```
<?php
if ( have_posts() ) : 

    while ( have_posts() ) : 
        the_post(); 
        get_template_part( 'content', 'archive' );
    endwhile; 

else :
    get_template_part( 'content', 'none' ); 

endif;
?>
```

In some categories I have lots of articles, therefore pagination is necessary. If I define in the WP settings the max number of posts that are shown (e.g. 20) then no pagination is visible on the archive page.

Therefore my questions are:

1. Can I paginate the main loop anyhow and if yes, how?
2. Or should I use a WP query that can be paginated? (I tried it, but it did not show the right articles anymore.) If so: how that query might look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to paginate the main loops (on archive.php) file:

```
<?php if (have_posts()):
    while (have_posts()):
        the_post();

        get_template_part("content", "archive");
    endwhile;

    // Add pagination links
    the_posts_pagination([
        "mid_size" => 2,
        "prev_text" => __("Previous", "textdomain"),
        "next_text" => __("Next", "textdomain"),
    ]);
else:
    get_template_part("content", "none");
endif; ?>
```